# How do I install Remix OS in GNOME Boxes?

Tags: android, virtualization, qemu

[Remix OS](http://www.jide.com/en/remixos-for-pc) is an interesting desktopification of Android. It can run off a read-write-able USB stick but it *doesn’t have an installer*. I can boot it up in [GNOME Boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes) just fine, but as I’m just running an ISO file it’s not a persistent read-write system. How do I install from Remix OS’ ISO file onto the hard drive inside Boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Press the TAB key at the first menu  (where you would choose between running in "Resident" or "Guest" mode) and add INSTALL=1 to the boot parameters. Check here for more info: http://fatminmin.com/blog/install-remix-os-to-disk.html